# Way to temporarily draw a uv grid over blender meshes?

Tags: materials, scripting, 3d-view

I have a scene where all of the objects have a material assigned to them.  However, it would be useful if I could temporarily assign them a special material which simply a texture map of a grid square.  The point of this would be to let me see the UV lines to help me make editing decisions.

As far as I can tell, Blender does not allow you to do this.  Am I wrong?  Is there some way to temporarily view my scene with this grid material and then switch back to the materials I've assigned?

Comment: It seems that there used to be such a feature, but it was removed for some reason - People complain a lot about it in this post, but there doesn't seem to be any real solution - https://blenderartists.org/t/uv-texture-preview-in-the-3d-view-in-blender-2-8/1144916

Comment: Cycles has a render-layer material override feature where you can render your scene with all materials replaced with the override material. Is that the kind of feature you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your object, in a shader editor window create an image texture node, create a new UV grid image, mantaine the node unconnected and selected.

In the 3d window you can now select the solid viewport shading, in texture mode, to show your UV Grid.

By selecting the material texture nodes you can display the UV grid or the material images.

[image]